# How to filter array of objects and get filtered object value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array model as below:

```
nodes:[
 { id: 1, label: 'label1'},
 { id: 2, label: 'label2'},
 { id: 3, label: 'label3'}
]
```

I whant to get the label of node filtering by `id`

I tried the next way, but dont get it work

```
const selectedNode = 2;

const nodeLabel = nodes.filter(({id}) => id.label ? id === selectedNode) // its filter here
```

Comment: What was the error/problem you got?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` method by passing a `callback` provided function.

The `find()` method **returns** the value of the first element in the array that passed the provided testing function. Otherwise `undefined` is returned.

```js
let nodes=[
 { id: 1, label: 'label1'},
 { id: 2, label: 'label2'},
 { id: 3, label: 'label3'}
];
let id=2;
let node = nodes.find(a=>a.id == id);
console.log(node ? node.label : 'id not found');
```

Answer (score 1):

`nodes.find(node => node.id === selectedNode).label`

Answer (score 1):

You were quite close.

This line

```
nodes.filer(({id}) => id.label ? id === selectedNode)
```

has few issues (*assuming filer was just a typo*)

- It is comparing an integer with an object. (**id** is the object here)
- `filter` will give you the **list of objects** rather than its property `label`.
- You were comparing `label` with `id` value.
- `{id}` to be replaced by `id`.

**Just modify this to**

```
nodes.filter( (id) => id.id === selectedNode )[0].label
```

**Demo**

```js
var nodes = [
 { id: 1, label: 'label1'},
 { id: 2, label: 'label2'},
 { id: 3, label: 'label3'}
];
var selectedNode = 2;
console.log( nodes.filter( (id) => id.id === selectedNode )[0].label );
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways you could do what you're trying to do. Here are a couple using native Array methods.

1. Chain `filter` and `map` and destructure the returned array.

   ```
   const [nodeLabel] = nodes
     .filter(({id}) => id === selectedNode)
     .map(({label}) => label)
   ```
2. Use `reduce`

   ```
   const nodeLabel = nodes
     .reduce((returnValue, item) => {
       if (item.id === selectedNode) return item.label
       return returnValue
     })
   ```